# How to navigate to different URLs based on the Images clicked in Notification?

Tags: android, layout, push-notification, carousel

I implemented Carousel Notifications in android by referring [this](https://medium.com/@rohitpaneliya/notification-image-slider-example-in-android-7f3c65b5bda0) link.
Everything went well and able to fetch the images as expected. The problem is, as per my requirement, I need to navigate to different URLs based on image clicked. But when I try to achieve this, I'm able to navigate to only one URL (Example: I have 3 images and 3 URLs. If I click on Second Image I need to navigate to second URL, but which ever the image is clicked, only navigating to third URL. )

below is the code attached for my notification and JSON.

```
 public void setNotification(String notification, String title, Bitmap bitmap, Bitmap bitmapIcon,
                            String uri,String WSC_ID,String fcmOperator, String fcmAccessToken,
                            String User_Id, String push_UID, List<Carousel> carouselList, String display_type){

    Intent urlIntent=null;

    //notification Id
    int m = (int) ((new Date().getTime() / 1000L) % Integer.MAX_VALUE);

    RemoteViews bigView = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(),
            R.layout.customlayout);


    //close button
    Intent closeButtonIntent = new Intent(context, NotificationReceiver.class);
    closeButtonIntent.setAction("CLOSEACTION");
    closeButtonIntent.putExtra("notificationId", m);
    closeButtonIntent.putExtra("closeAction","close");
    closeButtonIntent.putExtra("WSC_ID",WSC_ID);
    closeButtonIntent.putExtra("Access_Token",fcmAccessToken);
    closeButtonIntent.putExtra("status",notificationStatus);
    closeButtonIntent.putExtra("user_Id",User_Id);
    closeButtonIntent.putExtra("operator",fcmOperator);
    closeButtonIntent.putExtra("push_UID", push_UID);


    PendingIntent dismissIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, m, closeButtonIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
    bigView.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.crossmark,dismissIntent);

    bigView.setTextViewText(R.id.titleTv,title);
    bigView.setTextViewText(R.id.messageTv,notification);
    bigView.setImageViewBitmap(R.id.smallIcon,bitmapIcon);

    //for display_type = banner/text
    if (display_type.equalsIgnoreCase("Banner") || display_type.equalsIgnoreCase("Text")){
        bigView.setViewVisibility(R.id.viewFlipper, View.GONE);
        //for display_type = banner
        if (display_type.equalsIgnoreCase("Banner")){
            bigView.setImageViewBitmap(R.id.bannerImageView, bitmap);
            bigView.setViewVisibility(R.id.bannerImageView, View.VISIBLE);
        }

        urlIntent = new Intent(context, Office24by7UrlActivity.class);
        urlIntent.putExtra("uri",uri);
        urlIntent.putExtra("notificationId", m);
        urlIntent.putExtra("urlAction","urlAction");
        urlIntent.putExtra("WSC_ID",WSC_ID);
        urlIntent.putExtra("Access_Token",fcmAccessToken);
        urlIntent.putExtra("status",notificationStatus);
        urlIntent.putExtra("user_Id",User_Id);
        urlIntent.putExtra("operator",fcmOperator);
        urlIntent.putExtra("push_UID", push_UID);

        PendingIntent nextIntent=PendingIntent.getActivity(context,m,urlIntent,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        bigView.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.customlayoutRl, nextIntent);
    }

    //for CarouselNotification
    if (carouselList.size() > 0){
        for (int i=0; i<carouselList.size(); i++){
            RemoteViews remoteViews = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.image_layout);
            URL url = null;
            try {

                url = new URL(carouselList.get(i).getImgs());
                HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                connection.setDoInput(true);
                connection.connect();
                InputStream input = connection.getInputStream();
                Bitmap bitmap1 = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);

                bigView.setViewVisibility(R.id.viewFlipper, View.VISIBLE);
                bigView.setViewVisibility(R.id.bannerImageView, View.GONE);
                bigView.setDisplayedChild(R.id.viewFlipper, i+1);

                remoteViews.setImageViewBitmap(R.id.largeIconIv, bitmap1);

                Intent intent = new Intent(context, ViewFlipperWidgetProvider.class);

                bigView.setRemoteAdapter(R.id.viewFlipper, intent);

            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


            //click events
            urlIntent = new Intent(context, Office24by7UrlActivity.class);
            urlIntent.putExtra("uri", carouselList.get(i).getImgurl());
            urlIntent.putExtra("notificationId", m);
            urlIntent.putExtra("urlAction","urlAction");
            urlIntent.putExtra("WSC_ID",WSC_ID);
            urlIntent.putExtra("Access_Token",fcmAccessToken);
            urlIntent.putExtra("status",notificationStatus);
            urlIntent.putExtra("user_Id",User_Id);
            urlIntent.putExtra("operator",fcmOperator);
            urlIntent.putExtra("push_UID", push_UID);

            PendingIntent nextIntent=PendingIntent.getActivity(context,m,urlIntent,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
            remoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.largeIconIv, nextIntent);

            // Adding each image view in the viewflipper.
            bigView.addView(R.id.viewFlipper, remoteViews);
        }

    }

    NotificationManager mNotifyManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    NotificationCompat.Builder mNotifyBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context);
    foregroundNote = mNotifyBuilder.setContentTitle(title)
            .setContentText(notification)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
            .setLargeIcon(bitmapIcon)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .build();
    foregroundNote.bigContentView = bigView;

    assert mNotifyManager != null;
    mNotifyManager.notify(m, foregroundNote);


    if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT>=Build.VERSION_CODES.O){
        String channelId="CustomLibrary";
        NotificationChannel notificationChannel=new NotificationChannel(channelId,"CustomLibrary Notification",NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH);
        Notification testNotification=new Notification.Builder(context,channelId)
                .setContentTitle(title)
                .setContentText(notification)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
                .setLargeIcon(bitmapIcon)
                .setCustomBigContentView(bigView)
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .build();
        mNotifyManager.createNotificationChannel(notificationChannel);
        mNotifyManager.notify(m,testNotification);
    }
}//end of setNotification
```

My Notification layout(customLayout):

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/customlayoutRl">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/smallIcon"
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:gravity="center"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/titleTv"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/smallIcon"
            android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:hint="title" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/messageTv"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:maxLines="3"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/titleTv"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/smallIcon"
            android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
            android:hint="message" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/crossmark"
            android:src="@drawable/crossmark"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="20dp" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/bannerImageView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/messageTv"
            android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
            android:visibility="gone"/>

        <ViewFlipper
            android:id="@+id/viewFlipper"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/messageTv"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
            android:autoStart="true"
            android:flipInterval="2500"
            android:inAnimation="@android:anim/slide_out_right"
            android:outAnimation="@android:anim/slide_in_left"
            android:visibility="gone">

        </ViewFlipper>

 </RelativeLayout>
```

image_layout.xml:

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/largeIconIv"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:src="@drawable/crossmark"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" />
```

Kindly help me to navigate to the different URLs based on the image clicked.
Thanks In Advance..

Comment: You need to use different request codes for each `PendingIntent nextIntent`. Currently, you're using the same value for each – `m` – and the `FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT` is causing each subsequent `getActivity()` call to update the extras on the one same `PendingIntent`.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response @Mike. According to you, do I need to use different values of m for each Image??

Comment: You just need to use different values for each `getActivity()` call. It doesn't necessarily have to be `m`, if you're using `m` for something else, too. You could just use the loop index – `i`.

Comment: So Inside the getActivity() method, I replaced **m** with loop index **i**. I will test and let you know..

Comment: Hi Mike!! I edited the code as you suggested, Still no luck. Below is the code after editing,  `PendingIntent nextIntent=PendingIntent.getActivity(context,i,urlIntent,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
                remoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.largeIconIv, nextIntent);`

Comment: OK, I'll run a test here in a little bit. I've never actually done a `RemoteViews` with a `ViewFlipper` before, so I'm not certain of the behavior. The overwriting `PendingIntent` gets was just the first problem I noticed.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/202400/discussion-between-venkat-maddy-and-mike-m).

Comment: Well, it works as expected for me. I can't really see what's wrong in your posted code, though. You have some extraneous and unnecessary stuff, however, so I would suggest you tighten things up a bit, to help narrow down the possible issues. For example, why are you calling `setRemoteAdapter()` for the `ViewFlipper`? That's not doing anything, since `ViewFlipper` is not an `AdapterView`. Also, why do you are you building and posting two separate `Notification`s, at least on Oreo and above? You might clean that up a little, or even just start a fresh project with the bare minimum for testing.

Comment: Thanks for the update... Will try as you suggested and get back to you..

Comment: FWIW, here's my simple test project: https://drive.google.com/file/d/16N4d5nbe3-AD_2AN2zGdOAipnq1-BPCG/view?usp=drivesdk. I exported it to a text file, 'cause it's not worth creating a whole repo for. It uses three local images from resources, and attaches the resource name to the `Intent`, rather than a URL. It shows a `Toast` in `MainActivity`'s `onNewIntent()`, so make sure to set the `launchMode` appropriately on the manifest `<activity>` element, if you run this as is.

Comment: Thanks Mike!!! Thanks for your Code.. I addition to your code, I added one switch case which gave me expected output without any issues.. I'll post the answer now..

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I got the answer. As per my requirement maximum of only 5 images will be displayed and minimum of One. So, I used a **switch** case inside a **for-loop** and got the desired output. I hope my code will be helpful for others who looks out for same scenario.

```
public void setNotification(String notification, String title, Bitmap bitmap, Bitmap bitmapIcon,
                            String uri,String WSC_ID,String fcmOperator, String fcmAccessToken,
                            String User_Id, String push_UID, List<Carousel> carouselList, String display_type){

    Intent urlIntent;

    //notification Id
    int m = (int) ((new Date().getTime() / 1000L) % Integer.MAX_VALUE);

    RemoteViews bigView = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(),
            R.layout.customlayout);


    //close button
    Intent closeButtonIntent = new Intent(context, NotificationReceiver.class);
    closeButtonIntent.setAction("CLOSEACTION");
    closeButtonIntent.putExtra("notificationId", m);
    closeButtonIntent.putExtra("closeAction","close");
    closeButtonIntent.putExtra("WSC_ID",WSC_ID);
    closeButtonIntent.putExtra("Access_Token",fcmAccessToken);
    closeButtonIntent.putExtra("status",notificationStatus);
    closeButtonIntent.putExtra("user_Id",User_Id);
    closeButtonIntent.putExtra("operator",fcmOperator);
    closeButtonIntent.putExtra("push_UID", push_UID);


    PendingIntent dismissIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, m, closeButtonIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
    bigView.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.crossmark,dismissIntent);

    bigView.setTextViewText(R.id.titleTv,title);
    bigView.setTextViewText(R.id.messageTv,notification);
    bigView.setImageViewBitmap(R.id.smallIcon,bitmapIcon);

    //for display_type = banner/text
    if (display_type.equalsIgnoreCase("Banner") || display_type.equalsIgnoreCase("Text")){
        bigView.setViewVisibility(R.id.viewFlipper, View.GONE);
        //for display_type = banner
        if (display_type.equalsIgnoreCase("Banner")){
            bigView.setImageViewBitmap(R.id.bannerImageView, bitmap);
            bigView.setViewVisibility(R.id.bannerImageView, View.VISIBLE);
        }

        urlIntent = new Intent(context, Office24by7UrlActivity.class);
        urlIntent.putExtra("uri",uri);
        urlIntent.putExtra("notificationId", m);
        urlIntent.putExtra("urlAction","urlAction");
        urlIntent.putExtra("WSC_ID",WSC_ID);
        urlIntent.putExtra("Access_Token",fcmAccessToken);
        urlIntent.putExtra("status",notificationStatus);
        urlIntent.putExtra("user_Id",User_Id);
        urlIntent.putExtra("operator",fcmOperator);
        urlIntent.putExtra("push_UID", push_UID);

        PendingIntent nextIntent=PendingIntent.getActivity(context,m,urlIntent,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        bigView.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.customlayoutRl, nextIntent);
    }

    //for CarouselNotification
    //If CarouselNotification is Empty
    if (carouselList.size() > 0){
        for (int i=0; i<carouselList.size(); i++){

            RemoteViews remoteViews = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.image_layout);
            URL url = null;
            try {

                url = new URL(carouselList.get(i).getImgs());
                HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                connection.setDoInput(true);
                connection.connect();
                InputStream input = connection.getInputStream();
                Bitmap bitmap1 = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);

                bigView.setViewVisibility(R.id.viewFlipper, View.VISIBLE);
                bigView.setViewVisibility(R.id.bannerImageView, View.GONE);


                remoteViews.setImageViewBitmap(R.id.largeIconIv, bitmap1);

            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            Log.d(TAG, "setNotification: "+i);
            //click events
            urlIntent = new Intent(context, Office24by7UrlActivity.class);
            switch (i){
                case 0:
                    urlIntent.putExtra("uri", carouselList.get(0).getImgurl());
                    break;
                case 1:
                    urlIntent.putExtra("uri", carouselList.get(1).getImgurl());
                    break;
                case 2:
                    urlIntent.putExtra("uri", carouselList.get(2).getImgurl());
                    break;
                case 3:
                    urlIntent.putExtra("uri", carouselList.get(3).getImgurl());
                    break;
                case 4:
                    urlIntent.putExtra("uri", carouselList.get(4).getImgurl());
                    break;

            }

            urlIntent.putExtra("notificationId", m);
            urlIntent.putExtra("urlAction","urlAction");
            urlIntent.putExtra("WSC_ID",WSC_ID);
            urlIntent.putExtra("Access_Token",fcmAccessToken);
            urlIntent.putExtra("status",notificationStatus);
            urlIntent.putExtra("user_Id",User_Id);
            urlIntent.putExtra("operator",fcmOperator);
            urlIntent.putExtra("push_UID", push_UID);

            PendingIntent nextIntent=PendingIntent.getActivity(context,i,urlIntent,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
            remoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.largeIconIv, nextIntent);

            // Adding each image view in the viewflipper.
            bigView.addView(R.id.viewFlipper, remoteViews);
        }
    }

    NotificationManager mNotifyManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT>=Build.VERSION_CODES.O){
        String channelId="CustomLibrary";
        NotificationChannel notificationChannel=new NotificationChannel(channelId,"CustomLibrary Notification",NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH);
        Notification testNotification=new Notification.Builder(context,channelId)
                .setContentTitle(title)
                .setContentText(notification)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
                .setLargeIcon(bitmapIcon)
                .setCustomBigContentView(bigView)
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .build();
        mNotifyManager.createNotificationChannel(notificationChannel);
        mNotifyManager.notify(m,testNotification);
    }else{
        NotificationCompat.Builder mNotifyBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context);
        foregroundNote = mNotifyBuilder.setContentTitle(title)
                .setContentText(notification)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
                .setLargeIcon(bitmapIcon)
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .build();
        foregroundNote.bigContentView = bigView;

        assert mNotifyManager != null;
        mNotifyManager.notify(m, foregroundNote);

    }
}//end of setNotification
```

My Special Thanks to **Mike** who responded very quickly..